# Perform String Function(s) Using l- or s- or apply AND Export to CSV with R

Tags: r, csv, data.table

Data:

```
dt <- data.table(uid = c("abc001", "abc002", "abc003"..."abc100"), 
                 coords=("36.8 x 108", "55.5 x -4.6", "37.2 x -84.0"..."55.5 x -4.6"))
```

Note: Any set of coordinates may be associated with more than one user id.  In this example, the dt would have 100 unique uids, but < 100 unique set of coordinates.

Goal: aggregate the data by coords so that each unique set of coordinates is associated with a set of userids.  That is:

```
coords                  uid
36.8 x 108              abc001
55.5 x -4.6             abc002, abc100
37.2 x -84.0            abc003
```

How would I accomplish this task?  The functions associated with the aggregation techniques I have found deal with performing mathematical operations on the data.  For example, if the uid information was actually recorded temperatures for the coordinates, I could readily use lapply in data.table's j variable and then group by coords.  In fact, I *did* use lapply along with list() in the j term, which produced a data.table that seemed to meet my needs.  Unfortunately, multiple uids are held as lists, a type that throws an error when used with write.csv or the ff package.

I even explored using some variation of ' unlist '.  However, maintaining the association between the uids and the coords becomes an issue at that point.

Finally, I produced the desired result in Calc after writing out the ungrouped data to a csv file by using a simple sort plus a couple of if statements.  It only works because the dataset is small, though.

Thoughts?

Comment: `dt[, .(uid = toString(uid)), by = coords]`??

Comment: Provide reproducible data which means one can copy it from your post and paste it into R.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you, your suggestion works quite well for me.  A fast, friendly answer - awesome.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck  Mea culpa.  I should've added a ' c ' between ' coords= ' and the ' ( '.  And I shouldn't have attempted to provide a sense of scale using the ellipses between the third and 100th values in the two vectors...uh, lists...oh, whatever - the columns in the data.table.  Despite my ham-handedness, Arenburg provided an elegant solution, so it worked out in the end.  I'll try to post to a higher standard the next time I have a question.  Cheers!

Comment: @DavidArenburg Indeed, the question you cited addresses the issue(s) I encountered.  If I had found it (I did search), I would have used one of the answers.  Of note, the answer uses DT[, list(id=paste(id, collapse=",")), by=brand]

Comment: @DavidArenburg ...continuing my previous comment...

v. your answer of 

dt[, .(uid = toString(uid)), by = coords]

If the methods have a significant time difference, it may be worthwhile to keep this post along with a note about the efficiency of one solution v. the other.